ESP-IDF VSCode CMake and other adventures
Im trying to set up ESP-IDF on my computer, and run VSCode to compile my code that 100% compiled on other machine.
But when i run VSCode, it's shows PROBLEMS (1)
[{
    "resource": "/E:/Espressif/tools/cmake/3.23.1/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake",
    "owner": "cmake-configure-diags",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "
    CMake Error at E:/Espressif/tools/cmake/3.23.1/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):The C compiler

  \"E:/Espressif/tools/cmake/3.23.1/bin\"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: E:/projects/SS_BusyBox_ESP32_v2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

  Run Build Command(s):C:/PROGRA~1/CMake/bin/ninja.exe cmTC_af20e && 
  CreateProcess failed. Command attempted:
  \"E:\\Espressif\\tools\\cmake\\3.23.1\\bin    -o CMakeFiles\\cmTC_af20e.dir\\testCCompiler.c.obj -c E:\\projects\\Project\\build\\CMakeFiles\\CMakeTmp\\testCCompiler.c\"
  ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: ╨Ю╤В╨║╨░╨╖╨░╨╜╨╛ ╨▓ ╨┤╨╛╤Б╤В╤Г╨┐╨╡.

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.",
    "source": "CMake (message)",
    "startLineNumber": 69,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 69,
    "endColumn": 10000,
    "relatedInformation": [
        {
            "startLineNumber": 39,
            "startColumn": 1,
            "endLineNumber": 39,
            "endColumn": 1000,
            "message": "In call to 'project' here",
            "resource": "/E:/projects/Project/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    ]
}]

"not able to compile a simple test program"
I realy don't know what to do, please help me!
I tryed to reinstall CMake, ESP-IDF fully reinstall with tools, i even run export.bat in ESP folder.
Im using Win10 system

Most of the paths have forward slashes (/) (like UNIX) but the path to the C file has back slashes (\\) like MS Windows/MS DoS.  I'm thinking it should be one or the other, but not both???   -->>> E:\projects\Project\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c\
